# Any blender GUI toolkit for use with Game engine?

Tags: game-engine

Is there any blender GUI toolkit/library (popup window + eventual window control, button, radio button, checklists, slider, enter text...) to use with blender game engine.

The purpose is to evoke, for example, a button, place it at a given coordinates, then add the appropriate sensor, controller and actuator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library called [bgui](https://github.com/Moguri/bgui) that makes creating GUI for the bge much easier.

There are two locations for the documentation, the old (but better) [google project wiki](https://code.google.com/p/bgui/wiki/HomePage) and the [read the docs page](http://bgui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

In a nutshell, add the bgui script to your project with a python controller in the logic editor. Use a always sensor to trigger the script to always run.

Next you add widgets or components to bgui with a line such as this (this will add a button).

```
# A FrameButton widget
self.btn = bgui.FrameButton(self.frame, 'button', text='Click Me!', size=[0.3, 0.1], pos=[0, 0.4], options=bgui.BGUI_DEFAULT | bgui.BGUI_CENTERX)
```